# Prevent runtime failure for empty @Value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to load a keystore and check the expiration date. So say I have two values

```
@Value(“${connections.keystoreA}”)
private String keystoreA;

@Value(“${connections.keystoreB}”)
private String keystoreB;
```

Some environments have 1 of these values, some have both. My question is, is there any way to prevent this from failing at runtime if one of the values isn’t there, other than using a default value?

Edit: I’d also like to make it so that I can add additional configs in the future, keystoreC, keystoreD, etc

Comment: Just for reference, [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do an if/else in your `application.properties` and set a default value.
For instance, your application.properties could be like:

```
my.connections.keystoreA=${connections.keystoreA:defaultA}
my.connections.keystoreB=${connections.keystoreB:defaultB}
```

The idea is: if `connections.keystoreA` does not exist, the string `defaultA` will be injected.

After that, you can inject the values:

```
@Value("${my.connections.keystoreA}") 
private String keystoreA;    
@Value("${my.connections.keystoreB}") 
private String keystoreB;
```

Doing this way, spring will not fail at runtime.

Another option is to use this if/else directely in the fields to set a default value if necessary:

```
@Value("${connections.keystoreA:defaultA}") 
private String keystoreA;    
@Value("${connections.keystoreB:defaultB}") 
private String keystoreB;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to accomplish this without modifying the yaml or using any default values?

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but I’d rather not modify the yaml file or using any default values.

Comment: @T.Phillips what is your expected behavior when no property is defined? You can set property through CLI *-Dmy.connections.keystoreA="some_value"*

Comment: @T.Phillips If you do not want to change your code, you should export  connections.keystoreA (if using Linux) before starting your application. I mean, using a bash script, you have to check if your variable exists and if don't, export it. Then, start the app.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't want to use default values and you don't want to have `Exception` at runtime, you should use the `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` bean.

Just `@Autowire` the Environment in your component, and use the `getProperty` method to get a property from the yml configuration.

For example, if you want to get the value for `my.connections.keystoreA` you will use:

```
String value = environment.getProperty("my.connections.keystoreA");
```

Now, if there is a value for this key in your yml file, that value will be stored in the `value` variable. If there is no value for that key, then the value of the `value` variable will be null.

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using ? I tested on 1.5.8 and there was no null pointer exception. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) also says that it returns null if there is no value. Can you show the code that you have tried ?

Comment: I used @AutoConfiguration to scan for values within one value in my yaml